# Login session with java, spring boot, h2. How to implement it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I'm doing a project on Intellij that needs a login and logout. I'm new to spring boot and i know exists spring boot security but i also saw that it wants roles that i don't need in my project.
Which is the best and simple way to develop them?

Comment: If you want to just test spring boot security , you can use inmemory db for testing.

Comment: You can start reading https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-and-registration for more info on spring based authentication

Comment: Also, don't consider the roles as an obstacle here. You can easily implement Spring Security with one role only.